# In Python, I have a Value Error in my line with .split(), returns 1 expected 2. Adding white space doesn't help. Issue with data.txt?

Tags: python, command-line, compiler-errors, readfile, valueerror

Apologies if that title was vague. First I'd like to say that I have read through every forum I can find on the Value Error in python, I've implemented them but my program still can not get past line 22. There is more explanation at the bottom but first I'll give you the "DL" haha.

I am writing a program that reads a data.txt file and displays the output. Here is the goal of the project

> Your output should look like:
>   Reading vertices for a polygon with 5 vertices... Vertex 1 has coordinates at (1.70, 4.90) Vertex 2 has coordinates at (6.10, 6.20)
>   
>   Vertex 5 has coordinates at (1.50, 1.40)
>
> ---
>
> Reading vertices for a rectangle having, (of course), 4 vertices... Vertex 1 has coordinates at (7.00, 5.00)
>   ...
>   Your program only needs to echo check the data; there is no requirement during this lab to construct polygon objects, rectangle objects, to do transformations, to undo transformations, or to find and print perimeter.

The error from my command line is:

```
Reading vertices for polygon with 5 vertices...
Vertex 1 has coordinates at (1.7, 4)
Vertex 2 has coordinates at (.9, 6.1)
Vertex 3 has coordinates at (6.2, 7.0)
Vertex 4 has coordinates at (2.8, 4.8)
Vertex 5 has coordinates at (0.1, 1.)
Reading vertices for polygon with 1 vertices...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Read.py", line 22, in <module>
  x, y = file.read(8).split( )
  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The code I have written is:

```
file = open("data.txt")

line = file.read(1).strip()

while line != 'Q':

    numVertices = file.read(3).strip()
    numVertices = int(numVertices)

if numVertices != 4:
    print("Reading vertices for polygon with " + 
str(numVertices) + " vertices...") 

else:
    print("Reading vertices for rectangle having " + 
str(numVertices) + " vertices...")

for i in range(int(numVertices)):

    x, y = file.read(8).split( )
    print("Vertex " + str(i + 1) + " has coordinates at (" + x + ", " + y + ")")

line = file.read(1).strip()

file.close()
```

And the data.txt file contains:

```
P  5
1.7   4.9
6.1  6.2
7.0  2.8
4.8  0.1
1.5  1.4
R  4
7.0  5.0
1.0  5.0
1.0  3.0
7.0  3.0
P  4
4.1  5.4
6.9  2.5
2.9  0.8
0.9   2.5
P  3
1.2  4.7
6.5  4.2
4.0  1.7
Q
```

**In line 22 I have tried adding to the .split(), I have added (" "), (", ") none of which have succeeded. I have tried to change the variables from int to float, but then I can't concatenate a string. So I am at a loss, would someone mind helping me find out what the issue is here? Thank you so much!**

Comment: Please clean up your formatting.  Your posted program fails to run, as the `while` loop body is missing.  Your data file is indented and double-spaced.  When I fix these two problems as best I can see, the program works beautifully -- no error.  Perhaps you have a blank line in the file that your program doesn't handle?

Comment: Is the data file supposed to have two spaces between coordinates?

Comment: @kabanus I assume so, the instructions said to copy and paste it exactly as it is. But I'm on a Mac so maybe the formatting is off? What do you think?

Comment: Why are you reading in bytes instead of simply taking an entire line at a time?

Comment: @KatyNichols: Try this: cut and paste your text, select what you just pasted, and then click on the "{}" icon.  This is "code" formatting, which will indent that block four spaces (that's how this format handles code).  You can see that I did this with some of your post.

Comment: did you try `"x = file.read(8).split()"` then use `x[0]` and `x[1]` in place of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Prune I gave it a try with the code you posted below. It still is saying File "Read.py", line 24, in <module>
    x, y = in_file.read(8).split( )

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yes I tried it and it still didn't appear to work. I tried commenting out my print statement and tried vals = in_file.read(8).split() and it said that int() is an invalid literal. I'm so confused and lost lol

Comment: @KatyNichols: Please apply basic debugging: *exactly* what is the string you're acting on?  You're not using my *exact* code, as the line in question is line 20 in my posting.  Also, the data file as I formatted it may no longer be *exactly* what you're using.

Comment: Chop the problem line into parts and see what's going on: `in_str = file.read(8)`, then `print(in_str)`, then `x = in_str.split()` should show the problem: unexpected input followed by the error you know so well.  :-)

Comment: @Prune I copy and pasted your code, I just have a comment at the top with my name and description so the line isn't correct sorry! But okay! I tried doing print(in_file.read(8).split() first, and then I tried doing what you suggested. It is printing out the number after the last decimal on a new line. The error says that value int() is an " invalid literal with base 10: '.0' ". I am honestly pretty daft here and I'm not sure what that base 10: '.0' part means.

Comment: I can't debug code fragments -- put the actual code into your posting so I can cut & paste.  Glad to hear about the line numbers.  The `int` failure is because you're still using that byte-oriented input instead of reading whole lines -- as I commented and `kabanus` answered.  You got your reading misaligned somehow, and tried to convert part of a float (with decimal point) to an integer, which is invalid.  Again, we're handicapped by the lack of complete information from you.  From here, I'm going to wait until you get everything cleaned up as requested (as covered by the posting guidelines).

Comment: I just saw the thing about adding whitespace. This is unrelated to my answer: observe         that `()` and `( )` (space in the second) are exactly the same in Python (and most programming languages). `(' ')` would have made more sense, but that is `split`'s default anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code it is expecting a **very** specified format. Observe what you do:

```
read(1)
```

That reads exactly one byte. Presumably expecting the type of polygon/quit. Then:

```
read(3).strip()
```

Why 3 bytes? Well, you are probably expecting a space after the letter, then the number specifying the amount of vertices, which **must** be 1 digit, and finally - the newline character. 3 bytes total. finally, for every vertex, you

```
read(8)
```

8 bytes - 3 for each coordinate (digit, decimal point, digit), a space between them, and finally the new line.

If there is any character out of place, it will break your code. You are expecting exact formatting. If you do not have to use `read`, then do not - there are easier ways, specifically reading line by line. If you must use read, then make sure the formatting of the file is correct. You have at least **2 spaces**, and **sometimes 3 spaces** in your provided sample - that will break your code. Finally, always try to debug small programs with printing - putting in your for loop:

```
for i in range(int(numVertices)):
    res = file.read(8).split()
    print(res)
    x,y = res
```

would have printed exactly what you were breaking on, and gave you a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you thank you! You definitely helped me understand better what I was doing. I knew that I had to do it but not necessarily why. Reformatting the data file and using 1 space in between values instead of 2 spaces worked excellently. I understand where I went wrong now, thank you!

Comment: @KatyNichols You are welcome. Remember, when reading your own code, read like a computer! And also spam print in your program to help you see what you are exactly doing.

Comment: Definitely. I for sure need to start debugging more and thinking by line instead of by group. This was great, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired the indentation in your code, intuiting where the `while` loop ends from the file handling.  I also changed the `file` variable name, as `file` is a pre-defined type that you do *not* really want to redefine.

The program appears to work.

```
in_file = open("data.txt")

line = in_file.read(1).strip()

while line != 'Q':

    numVertices = in_file.read(3).strip()
    numVertices = int(numVertices)

    if numVertices != 4:
        print("Reading vertices for polygon with " +
    str(numVertices) + " vertices...")

    else:
        print("Reading vertices for rectangle having " +
    str(numVertices) + " vertices...")

    for i in range(int(numVertices)):

        x, y = in_file.read(8).split( )
        print("Vertex " + str(i + 1) + " has coordinates at (" + x + ", " + y + ")")

    line = in_file.read(1).strip()

in_file.close()
```

Output:

```
Reading vertices for polygon with 5 vertices...
Vertex 1 has coordinates at (1.7, 4.9)
Vertex 2 has coordinates at (6.1, 6.2)
Vertex 3 has coordinates at (7.0, 2.8)
Vertex 4 has coordinates at (4.8, 0.1)
Vertex 5 has coordinates at (1.5, 1.4)
Reading vertices for rectangle having 4 vertices...
Vertex 1 has coordinates at (7.0, 5.0)
Vertex 2 has coordinates at (1.0, 5.0)
Vertex 3 has coordinates at (1.0, 3.0)
Vertex 4 has coordinates at (7.0, 3.0)
Reading vertices for rectangle having 4 vertices...
Vertex 1 has coordinates at (4.1, 5.4)
Vertex 2 has coordinates at (6.9, 2.5)
Vertex 3 has coordinates at (2.9, 0.8)
Vertex 4 has coordinates at (0.9, 2.5)
Reading vertices for polygon with 3 vertices...
Vertex 1 has coordinates at (1.2, 4.7)
Vertex 2 has coordinates at (6.5, 4.2)
Vertex 3 has coordinates at (4.0, 1.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp seems like problem solved.

I was working on it and came up with alternate solution.

If you like it, comment, I'll break down my method.

```
file = open("data.txt")

line = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(line)):
    if 'P' in line[i] or 'R' in line[i]:
        x = line[i].split()
        n_verts = x[1]
        n_verts = int(n_verts)
        print("-"*47)
        print(f"Reading vertices for polygon with {n_verts} vertices...\n")
        for a in range(1, n_verts + 1): 
            verts = line[i+a].split()
            verts = ', '.join(verts)
            print(f"Vertex {a} has coordinates ({verts})")
```

> ```
> -----------------------------------------------
> Reading vertices for polygon with 5 vertices...
>
> Vertex 1 has coordinates (1.7, 4.9)
> Vertex 2 has coordinates (6.1, 6.2)
> Vertex 3 has coordinates (7.0, 2.8)
> Vertex 4 has coordinates (4.8, 0.1)
> Vertex 5 has coordinates (1.5, 1.4)
> -----------------------------------------------
> Reading vertices for polygon with 4 vertices...
>
> Vertex 1 has coordinates (7.0, 5.0)
> Vertex 2 has coordinates (1.0, 5.0)
> Vertex 3 has coordinates (1.0, 3.0)
> Vertex 4 has coordinates (7.0, 3.0)
> -----------------------------------------------
> Reading vertices for polygon with 4 vertices...
>
> Vertex 1 has coordinates (4.1, 5.4)
> Vertex 2 has coordinates (6.9, 2.5)
> Vertex 3 has coordinates (2.9, 0.8)
> Vertex 4 has coordinates (0.9, 2.5)
> -----------------------------------------------
> Reading vertices for polygon with 3 vertices...
>
> Vertex 1 has coordinates (1.2, 4.7)
> Vertex 2 has coordinates (6.5, 4.2)
> Vertex 3 has coordinates (4.0, 1.7)
> ```